# jms:listener-container acknowledge="transacted" not working

Tags: jms, spring-jms

We are trying to implement a durable subscriber using Spring JMS. Given below is how I've configured the durable subscribers. We are using Jackson message coverter, to convert incoming JSON to java object.

As per my understanding, if we mention **destination-type="durableTopic"** and **acknowledge="transacted"** in the jms:listener-container, message re-delivery would happen if exceptions are thrown while processing message in subscriber. However, for us, the message re-delivery is not happening if we encounter exceptions on our subscriber side. I've also given the java code snippet below.

We want to save the message into database. So, we tried a scenario where database is not started. So, here, the exception `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up` is thrown, but message re-delivery is not happening after this, whereas, we want the message to be redelivered (2-3 retries at least) for this scenario.

Also, I tried this same configuration and code inside a simple Spring MVC application and there, the messages are getting re-delivered whenever exceptions occur in app. So, not able to understand what is going wrong in this case. Could anybody help us here, identify what is the problem with configuration or code?

### Configuration in root-context.xml

```html
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
 <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
 
<bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter">
 <property name="typeIdPropertyName" value="__type" />
</bean>

<jms:listener-container connection-factory="amqConnectionFactory" destination-type="durableTopic" message-converter="messageConverter" acknowledge="transacted" client-id="svcOrdersSubscriber">
     <jms:listener destination="topicOrders" ref="ordersSubscriber" method="receive" subscription="ordersSubscription" />
</jms:listener-container>
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="amqConnectionFactory" destination-type="durableTopic" message-converter="messageConverter" acknowledge="transacted" client-id="svcResultsSubscriber">
     <jms:listener destination="topicResults" ref="resultsSubscriber" method="receive" subscription="resultsSubscription" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

### Java code

```
@Component("ordersSubscriber")
public class OrdersSubscriber {
    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;

    public void receive(Order order) {
        orderService.saveOrders(order);
    }

    public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }   
}
```

Comment: There must be something different in your configurations; if it "works" in an MVC app, it will work in a stand-alone JVM. Try turning on DEBUG logging and compare the two logs.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I checked the logs, in both places, I'm getting same exception: **org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'receive' threw exception; nested exception is ...** But the message redelivery is still failing.

Comment: However, I see in the sample MVC logs, log statements like this: **DEBUG org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext  - Begin:TX:ID:Venkatesh-PC-49787-1441952295550-1:1:1**. This same logs, I'm not able to see in the actual application. Not sure why the TransactionContext - Begin is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got resolved. I was using simple ActiveMQConnectionFactory in my MVC app, and here we were using ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory, but I think since the container was not supporting XA, transactions were not happening. Now, we switched to simple ActiveMQConnectionFactory, and things are working fine.